# how to workaround with Firebase asynch function call to make it act synchronously?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase

I want to finish firebase call before doing something else. Sample code below.
In the code below, I need to get the **final_output** after the two loops are done in a way if they were done in a synchronous way, but the problem in this case is that before the second firebase call returns, the two loops are completed with undesired final_output. Any **visual** help instead of theoretical explanations without any code? Thanks

I tried to use callbacks and promises, but either I used them in a wrong way or they are not for this situation. I also read a few similar posts, but they were either without any answer or the answer was not satisfying.

```
some_ref1.once('value', function(snapshot){
   // x is going to be a list 
   var x = snapshot.val();
   // looping through x
   for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
       // do something and get another list y

       // loop through y
       for (var j=0; j<y.length; j++){
           // go to firebase again
           some_ref2 = firebase.database().ref("some_other_location");
           some_other_location.once('value', function(snapshot)){
               var final_output = snapshot.val();
               console.log(final_output);
           }
       }
   }
})
```

Comment: You seem to be approaching this wrong. You don't want to make async code 'act synchronously' instead you should structure your code to work with the async pattern in the best way possible.

Comment: Anything asynchronous is going to involve the use of callbacks or promises. Promises are easier to work with.  Use them.  Even better, learn async/await syntax.